# Why is ExpressionEngine 1.6 control panel on localhost not responding?

Tags: apache, expressionengine

Since this morning my local install of EE 1.6.8 is failing to load the control panel at /cms. All that is being returned to the browser is:

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Redirect</title>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=index.php">

</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffffff">

</body>



</html>
```

I have no idea what might have changed. There is nothing in the php error log (error logging is switched on) or apache log. The main site loads fine. This is running locally on OSX Snow Leopard and was working fine so I am looking for debugging steps / advice from anyone who knows EE rather than 'oh, use MAMP' ;)

In config.php:

$conf['cp_url'] = "http://".$config_cp_url."/cms/index.php";

When trying to access http://local.mysite/cms/ the browser just hangs. PHP is NOT reaching a max execution limit which makes me think it is Apache causing the problem but I'm not sure what could have changed overnight.

UPDATE

here's the .htaccess file.

```
# secure .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>

# Dont list files in index pages
IndexIgnore *

# Simple 404 for missing files
<FilesMatch "(\.jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)$">
  ErrorDocument 404 "File Not Found"
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# Add a trailing slash to paths without an extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(_assets|_css|_scripts|_uploads|cms|robots\.txt|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Remove IE image toolbar
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
  Header set imagetoolbar "no"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Do you have anything new in your htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often a cookies issue. Try clearing your cache.

The HTML you're seeing is from the system/index.html file. You may have something causing a redirect like that in your htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks Philip. I have deleted all cookies, cleared cache etc. I have also included the contents of the .htaccess file above.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently when working on a site that was running 1.6.7. I was unable to solve it, but upgrading to the latest 1.7.x version (1.7.2 at the time) fixed it right up.